# What do "in-line" capacitors do?

Tags: capacitor

I know this is a basic question, but often I see a polarized capacitor in a signal circuit, like this:

[image]

Usually when I see that, the "signal destination" is an input pin on some IC and the capacitor is relatively close to it.

My understanding of capacitors is limited to when they're used to hold a charge, e.g. when used as a part of a low-pass filter.

What do they do when they are in-line like that? (And why are they always polarized?)

Comment: It's a DC blocking capacitor.  And NO, they are not always polarized.  It depends on the frequencies involved.  At audio frequencies, they may be polarized in order to get the capacitance you need (to limit the attenuation at low frequencies).  At RF (MHz, GHz) they are never polarized, at least that I've seen in practice,

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense re: polarization. I've only been looking at audio circuits; and the values seem to be in the single F range (like 4.7).

Comment: @JasonC That's *absurdly* high for any audio circuitry. Are you sure that isn't 4.7 μF?

Comment: @Hearth ‍♂️ I really have no clue what I'm talking about so you're probably right. [Here's a pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2rmW.png). Is it conventional to leave off the unit prefix if it's μ? If it is then it's 4.7μ.

Comment: @JasonC 4.7 farads is *enormous*, and those look like a normal size for 4.7 μF caps. 4.7 farad caps are either at least the size of a soda can, or weird shaped supercapacitors that wouldn't be in a package like that.

Comment: Search "capacitance of the earth" on Google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The capacitor charges up to the difference between the DC value of the signal source and the DC value of the signal destination.  For example, if an audio signal is centered about ground at its source, but the destination circuit has only a single power supply voltage so its input sits at its Vcc/2, maybe 6 Vdc for a 12 V circuit, then the capacitor will charge up to 6 V while passing the audio signal through with very little attenuation (assuming the capacitor value and the source and destination impedances do not form a high-pass filter that affects the frequencies of interest).  In this role, the cap is both a coupling capacitor and a DC-blocking capacitor.